# Is it possible to add ESLint directly to Git?

Tags: git, github, eslint, husky, lint-staged

I want ESLint to check my files before committing them to git. I found husky and lint-staged to do this but in this way every programmer has to have husky and lint-staged in their machine.

What if ESLint is directly injected into git so that all the commits are checked with ESLint, without every programmer having to install husky and lint-staged?

Comment: What does "directly injected into git" mean?

Comment: Why aren't husky and lint-staged in the `devDependencies` for the package they're working on, so they get installed along with everything else?

Comment: "directly injected to git" means, is there a way to add eslint to GIT so that no programmers have to install eslint, when they commit the eslint checks for violations and their code is allowed only when there are no violations.

Comment: jonrsharpe, yes  I agree with you that when a new programmer takes a PR (pull request) he/she can install them from the package.json, but what if a new programmer does not take PR but pushes a new file to a same branch in git. I am asking like that if we add eslint to a branch then who are all commiting to that branch should obey the rules of eslint, if their code violates eslint rules the commit is aborted. Thanks

Comment: Now it's changed to github? Which are you wanting? Git and github are different things

Comment: evolutionxbox, Thanks for replying, Its git actually, Is it possible to install eslint in git branch so that all the commits to that branch should obey the eslint rules. Could you relate what I am asking? If not let me explain my question with more details.

Comment: the approach I would use is the one that you've also disregarded.

Comment: evolutionbox, what is your suggestion, husky+ lint-staged ? I am new thats why I am confused, If I am wrong pls correct me,

Comment: do worry about making a wrong decision. go with husky + lint-staged, and remove it if it stops being helpful

Comment: Are your developers not installing the dependencies for the things they work on?! How do they get _any_ new dependency? How do they run the tests, run the code, make sure the changes are _working_? The default husky setup installs the hooks using the prepare script, they don't need to do anything special.

Comment: Thanks evolutionxbox and jonsharpe, thanks for your replies... I am set to use the husky+ lint-staged set up.

Comment: The short "executive summary" of your question and all the comments and answer is: "Git is a tool (set), not a solution". You're trying to treat Git as if it were a "business solution" (a single package that does everything), and, well, it's just *not*.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force people to run those programs on their machine or integrate them directly into Git.  People use all sorts of tools to interact with Git, some of which don't run hooks or external program at all (e.g., those using libgit2).  Anyone using regular Git can simply add `--no-verify` to `git commit` to bypass the hooks, [as outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks).

If you need to implement an effective control that makes sure that people's code meets some standard, you should use a CI system (e.g., GitHub Actions) and check that the code passes before merging it into the desired branch.

In addition, it's not even useful to install pre-commit hooks by default, as the FAQ mentions, because this means that advanced users who use lots of squash or fixup commits can end up frustrated by the fact that those commits are incorrectly flagged by the linter.